# Two dbcontexts cause an error "value cannot be null. parameter name entitytype"

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, entity, dbcontext

I have 2 `DbContext`s in my application, and need to do a join in 2 tables that are each one in a different `DbContext`; I get this error

> value cannot be null. parameter name entitytype

When I try to join 2 tables of the same context, this error does not happen.

```
var VerificaExistenciaSinistro = sinistroContext.SnsAviso
  .Join(
    sinistroContext.SnsNumAviso, 
    sinistro => sinistro.NumApo,
    aviso    => aviso.NumApo,
    (sinistro, aviso) => new { 
      sinistroV = sinistro, 
      avisoV = aviso })
  .Where(c => c.sinistroV.CodItm == c.avisoV.CodItm &&
    c.sinistroV.NumApo == c.avisoV.NumApo && 
    c.sinistroV.NumAvs == c.avisoV.SeqNumAvs)
  .Join(sgsContext.EmsEmissao,
    sinistro1 => sinistro1.sinistroV.CodCtrtAvs,
    emissao   => emissao.CodCtrt,
    (sinistro1, emissao) => new { 
      sinistroC = sinistro1, 
      emissaoC = emissao })
  .Where(c => c.sinistroC.sinistroV.CodCtrtAvs == c.emissaoC.CodCtrt && 
    c.emissaoC.CodEmis == c.sinistroC.avisoV.CodEms)
  .Where(x => x.sinistroC.sinistroV.NumApo == apolice &&
    x.emissaoC.StsEmis == emissao && 
    x.emissaoC.NumEndosso ==endosso && 
    x.sinistroC.sinistroV.CodItm == cod_itm && 
    x.sinistroC.sinistroV.CodCbe == cbeCod)
  .Select(x => x.sinistroC)
  .ToList();
```

Comment: What version of EF Core are you using? [This issue which is already resolved](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/11101) sounds very close to yours. Looks like they were using 2.0.1.

Comment: May I ask why you join between two different contexts? Do you understand that EF tries to translate each LINQ statement into SQL and that this SQL translation is confined to one context (= one coherent set of mappings)?

Comment: Hello Gert, I understand that EF is restricted to one context, but in that case is a refectory of a old procedure in a old system, and now is a API using EF, and in this proc, there some moments that joins some tables from some differents DB.

Answer (score 1):

It generally occurs when u query data from two dbcontext using IQueryable

I encountered the same issue when I was using two `dbContext`. The solution which I found was. If u are using join between two tables then load any one table's data first to a `variable/Object` so that It becomes `IEnumerable` or `IList` and then do join with that `variable/Object` to the another table of another `dbContext`

Example

```
    var FirstDbContextTable = sinistroContext.SnsAviso
  .Join(
    sinistroContext.SnsNumAviso, 
    sinistro => sinistro.NumApo,
    aviso    => aviso.NumApo,
    (sinistro, aviso) => new { 
      sinistroV = sinistro, 
      avisoV = aviso })
  .Where(c => c.sinistroV.CodItm == c.avisoV.CodItm &&
    c.sinistroV.NumApo == c.avisoV.NumApo && 
    c.sinistroV.NumAvs == c.avisoV.SeqNumAvs).ToList();


var result=FirstDbContextTable.Join(sgsContext.EmsEmissao,
    sinistro1 => sinistro1.sinistroV.CodCtrtAvs,
    emissao   => emissao.CodCtrt,
    (sinistro1, emissao) => new { 
      sinistroC = sinistro1, 
      emissaoC = emissao })
  .Where(c => c.sinistroC.sinistroV.CodCtrtAvs == c.emissaoC.CodCtrt && 
    c.emissaoC.CodEmis == c.sinistroC.avisoV.CodEms)
  .Where(x => x.sinistroC.sinistroV.NumApo == apolice &&
    x.emissaoC.StsEmis == emissao && 
    x.emissaoC.NumEndosso ==endosso && 
    x.sinistroC.sinistroV.CodItm == cod_itm && 
    x.sinistroC.sinistroV.CodCbe == cbeCod)
  .Select(x => x.sinistroC)
  .ToList();
```